# Making archive with the current date as folder name

Tags: backup, archive, cpio

I am looking to make an archive of my root directory, but only certain folders/files. So far, this is what I have, can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? For the purposes of figuring out the issue, I've got 3 test files (test1, etc) in the /home/user directory that I'm trying to archive with cpio, with the folder name being the date. Bear with me, as I'm fairly new at this. Thanks.

`today="$(date +%m%d%Y)"`

`mkdir /home/user/backuptest/$today`

`LIST="test1 test2 test3"`

`for i in $LIST`

`do`

`find $i -print | cpio -pduv /home/user ;`

`find $i -print | cpio -pduv /home/user/backuptest/$today`

`done`

Answer (score 0):

Excerpts of my home backup script, for what it's worth:

```
set DIRS = "/etc /root /usr/home /usr/local/etc"
set TMPFILE = /tmp/tar-`date "+%F_%T"`.tmp
set FILENAME = /backup/backup-`hostname -s`_`date "+%F"`.tbz

# Build list of files to be backed up
foreach LOCATION ($DIRS)
    find $LOCATION -type fl >> $TMPFILE
end

# Do actual backup
tar cyfTP - $TMPFILE | dd bs=10k of=$FILENAME

# Cleanup list of files
rm -f $TMPFILE
```

<sub>Note: There's a lot of round about ways of doing things in there because I actually pipe the archive through LZMA Compression, Blowfish Encryption, Full/Incremental/Differential Backups, and write to either File or Tape.</sub>

Comment: This leads me to my next question...I continuously receive the "cpio: cannot open file" error, even though I have full permission over them. Thanks

Comment: A guess, you've got directories in there and `find` will print them by default if you don't add `-type fl` arguments.

Comment: It still seems to be pushing out the "permission denied, can't open" error. I removed -print and just put -type f, and it is still returning that message. (-type fl returned "type arg must be 1 character) Thanks

Comment: What OS is this exactly?

Comment: Hi, this is on an Ubuntu server, but I've figured out the permission issue. Thanks